# Equivalence relation that works for infinite dimensional vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, relations

We had subspaces of $V$,  $U_1$ and $U_2$ that had and equivalence relation ~ defined. It is defined as an automorphism $f: V \rightarrow V $ where $f(U_1)=U_2$.

In this case, the two vector spaces are equivalent to each other if their dimensions are finite and equal.

What I'm interested in, in this case, is if there is some kind of characterisation for this relation that also works in infinite dimensional spaces - for example something with a codimension, but I can't seem to find anything that can resemble it closely.

Comment: If seems to me that - if subspaces $U_1,U_2$ are by definition equivalent iff some automorphism $f$ exists s.t. $f(U_1)=f(U_2)$ - then the spaces are equivalent iff they are isomorphic. If at least one of the spaces has finite dimension then they are isomorphic iff their dimensions are equal.

Comment: Any isomorphism between any pair of subspaces of $V$ can be extended to (if it isn't already) a homomorphism $V\to V$. And two subspaces have equal dimension iff they are isomorphic.  So I don't see anything that needs to be changed. What do you think fails?

Comment: certainly weirder things begin to happen: for example, you can have subspaces that are equivalent to proper subspaces (which is something that doesn't happen with the finite dimensional version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply your definition to an arbitrary $V$. What you would obtain is that $U_1$ and $U_2$ are equivalent if and only if both their dimensions and codimensions agree.

It is very easy to prove this, by using that you can always extend a basis from a subspace to the whole space, and using that an automorphism will send a linearly independent set into another linearly independent set.